# GitHub Pages, return me a error 404

Tags: github

This is my user on github: funnyfrontend

I follow the steps to create a GitHub page:

1- My Repository (same url that user on github):
https://github.com/funnyfrontend/funnyfrontend.github.io

2- The url:
http://funnyfrontend.github.io

But, the url return me the 404.

What´s is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: your repo is empty...

Comment: I'd try adding `index.html`

Comment: Yes, just I´m add a index.html sample

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/funnyfrontend is your profile GitHub Page.

https://github.com/funnyfrontend/*YOUR_REPOSITORY_NAME* is the URL to your repository you have created. Multiple Repositories are possible.

Those are the only URLs that are provided/created from GitHub for you when you create an account there. Forget the URL you mentioned in point 2, it does not exist.

Comment: Men, I want create a github page with my projects, I follows this steps:[link](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/)